# Formula field in word template mail merge

Tags: document, template, mail-merge

I'm trying to include a formula field in my word template to do mail-merging but my formula field does not appear. Other custom fields shows properly but not my formula fields.

Any help??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Javier - which Salesforce product are you referencing in this question?  Also, see [ask] on getting the most from the Community

Comment: @cropredy Is salesforce service, I'm using the mail merge templates in order to create a word document which gets values form salesforce fields. My issue is that the formula fields does not appear with the value in the final document so I'm looking for a workaround or any way to solve that. Thanks.

Comment: Please use [edit] and post your template and formula field